# setting a string variable for a specific context

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

```
import gzip
with gzip.open('File_name', 'rb')as f:

for line in f:
    line.decode("utf-8") #Is this how I transfer bytes to string in this context ?

print(line)


doc = nlp(line)* #If I define "line", it would give an output of the entire text instead of below"

print("Abbreviation", "\t", "Definition")

for abrv in doc._.abbreviations:
print(f"{abrv} \t ({abrv.start}, {abrv.end}) {abrv._.long_form}")
```

How do I set a string variable to "line" so I can input it into the nlp function ?
I've tried setting a definition for it, but it would print out the entire texts instead of running the abbreviation outputs.

Comment: Please supply the expecte [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Your wording doesn't quite specify what you're trying to do, and much of your posted code is not related to the problem.

Comment: I just edited it, and I apologize the lack of clarity and extra wordings, since I'm new to python. The reason I leave the gzip import and other extra info is that I feel it would be relevant to the context of the problem

Comment: It's also not entirely clear what the problem is: are you getting an error? If so, can you post the trace? Or are you seeing results that differ from what you want? If so, what exactly are the expected and actual results?

Answer (score 0):

The code is a little difficult to read because the indentations don't match.
But could you try with:

```
line = line.decode("utf-8")
```

In Python, a string is immutable, so whenever you perform a function on a string, you need to capture the result in a variable, either a new var or an existing var.